# add or delete from the beginning item of an array without using shift/unshift/loop in js

Tags: javascript

I need to write a simple `js` code to **add** or **delete** from the beginning item of an array without using `shift`/`unshift`/`loop`.

I was able to add items successfully but the delete operation can't be done.

**My js code**:

```
var array = [100, 200, 300]
var newFirstElement = 17
var array = [newFirstElement].concat(array) // add in begainning
console.log(array);

array = array.splice(0,1) // remove from begaining
console.log(array);
```

**Output:**

```
[ 17, 100, 200, 300 ]
[ 17 ]
```

How can I successfully delete item from the beginning of the array maintaining given conditions?

Comment: Don't assign the result of `splice` method call to the `array` variable; `splice` method mutates the array in-place: `array = array.splice(0,1)` ---> `array.splice(0,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splice` returns the removed elements. So, you need not to assign `array` variable to it.

```js
var array = [100, 200, 300]
var newFirstElement = 17
var array = [newFirstElement].concat(array) // add in begainning
console.log(array);

array.splice(0, 1) // remove from begaining
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly, no need to overwrite the array with the new splice

```
array.splice(0,1) // remove from begaining
console.log(array);
```

It will give you what you need:
[100, 200, 300]